# cross compilation of opencv for arm

Tags: arm

I am a newbie to ARM. I am trying to cross compile opencv 2.3.1 for ARM9 board with linux 2.3
After generating a cmake file when i make i get the error as follows

Desktop/opencv/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h: In function 'T cvflann::abs(T) [with T = long double]':

OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h:63: error: 'fabsl' was not declared in this scope

make[2]: *** [modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann.dir/src/precomp.obj] Error 1

make[1]: *** [modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Thanx all

Answer (score 1):

double and long double are the same on ARM. It looks like fabsl was just removed from libstdc++.

I had the same problem when compiling for my ARM board. Replace fabsl() with fabs() in
/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h

This gets things compiling, I have not tested the build yet as I am still cross compiling some other deps first. Good luck!

John